# How to make this chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I'm trying to make a chart like this using JS, HTML and CSS only:
[image: chart]

It must have all the things labels, colors and start from 0%. The value is based on user score from quiz in %. When a user gets 5/10 points, the value is 50%. If the user gets -5/10 points, the value is -50%.

This code is the last idea i had, but the negative value didn't show and it wasn't starting at 0% (center div). Also it was changing the width so the center div wasn`t in the center.

```js
if (successRate > 0) {
  plus.style.width = (successRate / 100) * 300 + "px";
  minus.style.display = "hidden";
} else if (successRate < 0) {
  minus.style.width = (successRate / 100) * 300 + "px";
  plus.style.display = "hiden";
}
```

```css
#chart {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#chart>* {
  height: 30px;
}

#left {
  height: 29px;
  background: red;
  display: table-cell;
}

#center {
  max-width: 1px !important;
  background: #000;
  display: table-cell;
}

#right {
  height: 29px;
  background: green;
  display: table-cell;
}

#container {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section id="chart">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="center">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="right">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Sorry but third-party charting libraries aren't allowed?

Comment: You should add the HTML, CSS, and JS you've tried to your question, even if it's not working properly.

Comment: Show us what you've tried to cook up, we'll help you from there.

Comment: third-party charting libraries well i can use them but i dont know any. I'll add the last code,

Comment: Posted an explained solution, hope it helps :)

Comment: @highdef Very well explained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: In practical use, you need to change just two things in
>   javascript to make it work for your implementation.
>
> - **First**: `var successRate = document.getElementById("rate").value;` We're giving values using this
>     text input, but you can pass your value to successRate in anyway you
>     desire.
> - **Second:** You can change the maxRate which is set to 10 in the code(then use values between -10 and 10) to whatever value you desire
>     and it will compute the percentage width of the progress bar respect
>     to that value.
>     **That's it!**

**You can make use of the following implementation, it is simple and yet effective for varying values.**

- We're making use of a **center** div , a **bar** div which will *propagate and change color* depending on the **successrate** and a **percent** container which dynamically displays the percentage below the bar.
- By default we're positioning the center div in center with absolute positioning and bar at the **left:50% with top:0** with relation to **container** having **relative positioning**.

**Now how the does the javascript work?**

We're obtaining the rate in a textbox and saving it in `successRate` and we're using `bar` as the variable *to manipulate the **progress bar***.

We have set the maximum marks for this 10, in maxrate which **can be changed making it flexible**.

Then, using if/else condition we can compare when the value entered is positive or negative. If positive or negative we've cooked up a formula to increase % width in that direction.

We're making use of `var prograte = (100*Math.abs(successRate))/(2*maxrate);` to **calculate the width** of our progress bar ( the abs method incase the successrate is negative).

> Eg, If score is 10/10 then **10 is the success** rate and **10 is the max
>   rate**. Using the formula:
>
> ```
> prograte = (100*successRate)/(2*maxrate)
> ```
>
> We obtain, prograte = 100*10 / 2*10 = 50% thus giving it 50% width from the center. If score is 2/10 we obtain,
>   100*2/2*10 = 10% of the width.

When `successrate > 0`, we're starting from the *center to the right. So, we move the **left to 50%**.*
And using the above computed value of forward we ***increase the width of bar*** to that and **change the color to green**.

But when the `successrate < 0` (i.e the else condition we **multiply it by -1 to get the absolute value** of the width) then, we *compute on how much further we have to move from the left* using `(50% - prograte)` that we compute, which puts it to the right side of the center bar.

> Eg, If score is -5/10 then **-5 is the success rate** and **10 is the max
>   rate**. Using the formula:
>
> ```
> prograte = (100*successRate*(-1))/(2*maxrate)
> ```
>
> We obtain, prograte = 100*5 / 2*10 = 25% and using (50%-prograte) we obtain 25%. So, we move to `25% from the left` and set the `width to 25%` which makes it look like its in the center decreasing backwards.

To display the percentage when the **flag!=1** *(which identifies if the limit for the value has been crossed)*, we make use of:

```
var percent = document.getElementById("percent");
percent.style.left = "percentage %";
percent.style.color = "color";
percent.innerHTML = prograte * 2 + "%";
```

```js
function changerate() {
  var successRate = document.getElementById("rate").value;
  var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
  var flag = 0;
  var percent = document.getElementById("percent");
  var maxrate = 10;
  var prograte = (100 * Math.abs(successRate)) / (2 * maxrate);
  if (successRate >= 0 && successRate <= maxrate) {
    bar.style.left = "50%";
    bar.style.background = "green";
    bar.style.width = prograte + "%";
  } else if (successRate < 0 && (-1 * maxrate) <= successRate) {
    bar.style.background = "red";
    bar.style.width = prograte + "%";
    bar.style.left = (50 - prograte) + "%";
  } else {
    alert("Limit crossed");
    bar.style.left = "50%";
    bar.style.width = "0%";
    flag = 1;
  }
  if (flag != 1) {
    if (successRate > 0) {
      percent.style.left = 50 + prograte + "%";
      percent.style.color = "green";
    } else {
      percent.style.left = 50 - prograte + "%";
      percent.style.color = "red";
    }
    percent.innerHTML = prograte * 2 + "%";
  } else {
    percent.style.left = prograte + "%";
    percent.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```css
#chart {
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

#container {
  height: 29px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

#percent {
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 50%;
  font-weight:bold;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#bar {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#center {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 2px !important;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
Current max value : (10 which can be modified in javascript in maxrate)
<br><br> Input values between -10 and 10 : <br>
<input type="text" id="rate" />
<input type="button" value="update" onclick="changerate()" />

<section id="chart">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="center">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div id="percent"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Gygram Your welcome :) Hope you get the explanation of its working well.

Comment: @Gygram Updated with a progress percentage.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, which certainly can be improved upon is as follows:

Create two container DIVs each containing one child DIV:

```
<div class="container" id="c1">
  <div class="bar" id="contra">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="c2">
  <div class="bar" id="pro">

  </div>
</div>
```

Assign them basic CSS properties, such as positioning and border:

```
.container {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}

#c1 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid;
}

#c2 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid;
}

#pro {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: -9999;
}

#contra {
  top: 0px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: -9999;
}
```

Now you already have all you need in terms of HTML/CSS. You have two DIVs that serve as containers and provide the black borders as shown in your image. You also have two bars inside those containers, each representing the percentage you want to display.

Obviously they would never be displayed as set with my demo-CSS-properties. As long as nothing has happened they should have zero width or be invisible and of course the bar-DIVs would never have a width above zero both at the same time.

Anyway, the dynamic part comes then with JavaScript:

```
var proBar = document.getElementById('pro');
var contraBar = document.getElementById('contra');
// ... do your quiz stuff and get the percentage from there
// ... calculate from the max-width of your container the position and 
width of the respective bar
var result = 70; // <-- your calculations go here

proBar.setAttribute("style","width:" + result + "px")
console.log("Done.");
```

The bars are what you want to be dynamic here. So you can set their width to zero in the CSS properties and dynamically assign width and positioning.

So for example your container has a width, which is now the max-width of the child-bar. You get your positive or negative percentage value fro myour quiz and then calculate the width the bar should have from the percentage of the max-width. Example: Your max-width is 200px, because that is the width of the container-DIVs. Your percentage you got from your quiz is 50 percent. Thus the width of the pro bar is 100px and the width of the contra bar is zero, since the percentage value is larger than zero.

For the contra bar you would have to also calculate the left position, not just width. You can get the width from the percentage as described above and then the value of left can be described by subtracting the calculated width from max-width.

You can figure out how to do that and how to calculate the percentage. It's rather simple, but this is obviously an assignment and you should do some work yourself.

You can see the manipulation of "pro" by changing the value of result. All this should be more than plenty to solve the problem you are having. Please give some feedback when you're done.

```js
var proBar = document.getElementById('pro');
var contraBar = document.getElementById('contra');
// ... do your quiz stuff and get the percentage from there
// ... calculate from the max-width of your container the position and width of the respective bar
var result = 70; // <-- your calculations go here

proBar.setAttribute("style","width:" + result + "px")
console.log("Done.");
```

```css
.container {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}

#c1 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid;
}

#c2 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid;
}

#pro {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: -9999;
}

#contra {
  top: 0px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: -9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="c1">
  <div class="bar" id="contra">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="c2">
  <div class="bar" id="pro">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Done. As described in my post it does not include the percentage calculation, as it is fairly simple and we do not know where his quiz data comes from. I have marked the position in the code where OPs calculations need to go and explained how to go about them.

Comment: Comment if a fully working snippet is required for understanding, including user input. If so I can edit that in once I get home, however it should be fairly obvious from the code itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another variant with less elements.

```js
function calculate(input) {
  var chart = document.getElementById('chart');
  var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
  var width = Math.abs(input.value) * (chart.clientWidth / 2) / 10;

  bar.style.width = width + 'px';

  if (input.value >= 0) {
    bar.style.left = chart.clientWidth / 2 + 'px';
    bar.style.background = 'green';
  } else if (input.value < 0) {
    bar.style.left = chart.clientWidth / 2 - width + 'px';
    bar.style.background = 'red';
  }
}
```

```css
#chart {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#chart:after {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#bar {
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="0" min="-10" max="10" onchange="calculate(this)">
<section id="chart">
  <div id="bar"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: You should explain your code to the OP and the future readers that might read this.

Comment: @Highdef, of course your explanation is great. But when personally I look for an answer, I prefer just to read the code.

Comment: If people just wanted the code, then they shouldn't use SO. This isnt a free get your solution and complete your work website. The aim for the answers is to provide an explanation of the code, for just not the satisfaction or benefit of one user but any and all. You'll see your answers voted down sooner or later even though you provide a working code with comments saying "explain your code" or "there's no explanation how does it work? "

Comment: @Highdef, everybody can use every website in this free Internet as they want. And of course, feel free to vote down my answer =)